# Mysql Error in Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I start working with Qt and MySQL on Linux Ubuntu 15.
I wrote this little program:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL"); 

//db.setHostName("localhost");
//db.setUserName("root");
//db.setPassword("1");
//db.setDatabaseName("mydatabase1");

if(db.open())
{
    qDebug() << "connected " << db.hostName();
}else{
qDebug() << "Connection FAILED.";
}

return a.exec();
```

But it gives me this:

> ERROR :<< QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded >>

I have some libraries in the `sql` folder in Qt:

- libqsqlite.so
- libqsqlmysql.so
- libqsqlpsql.so

My Qt is 5.7.0.
What do I have to do?

Comment: Is your Qt build with SQL driver support enabled? Is a QCoreApplication instance started beforehand ([last paragraph](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-programming.html))? How do you compile your program? Have you tried using a debugger to see where it fails?

Comment: @Torbjörn i'm running on linux by the way . i don't use debugger for it because i know the problem is in first LINE .

Comment: The debugger won't just tell you the line number where the error appears.

Comment: Try check available drivers with QSqlDatabase::drivers() first.

Comment: Did you install the SQL drivers using your package manager, or by hand?  If the former, then the path should be correct; if the latter, you'll need to tell Qt where to find them.

Comment: Is this is a run-time, rather than compile-time, error?  Please [edit] your question to clarify, and also give the full path to the `sql` directory containing your libQtSQL plugins.